# How to check a dynamic attribute of one object in PHP ?

Tags: php, object, key

In php, I must check if the first attribute of a PHP object is null. the problem is I do not know the key because the object is set dynamicaly and can be an Object A or Object B etc...

```
if( empty( $this->editable_item->item ) || $this->editable_item->item->? === null ){ <-- ? the key can be various things
   //Do something like log an error
}
```

How can check the first attribute without knowing its key ?

Comment: Relying on the order of properties is an awful idea as you will get dependencies between objects that are hard/impossible to track in case of errors. It would be better to have a well defined method to check for the required value or at least use an attribute with the same name for each object.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to use the function *get_object_vars()* and use *reset* like this :

```
$a_vars = get_object_vars( $this->editable_item->item  );
reset( $a_vars );
$first_key = key( $a_vars );
if( empty( $this->editable_item->item ) || empty( $a_vars[$first_key] ) ){   
   //Do something like log an error
}
```